# Treemap Problem

Tags: java, frequency, treemap

I am trying to count frequency of words in a text file. But I have to use a different approach. For example, if the file contains BRAIN-ISCHEMIA and ISCHEMIA-BRAIN, I need to count BRAIN-ISCHEMIA twice (and leaving ISCHEMIA-BRAIN) or vice versa. Here is my piece of code-

```
// Mapping of String->Integer (word -> frequency) 
    HashMap<String, Integer> frequencyMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); 

    // Iterate through each line of the file 
    String[] temp;
    String currentLine; 
    String currentLine2;
    while ((currentLine = in.readLine()) != null) { 

    // Remove this line if you want words to be case sensitive 
    currentLine = currentLine.toLowerCase();
    temp=currentLine.split("-");
    currentLine2=temp[1]+"-"+temp[0];

    // Iterate through each word of the current line 
    // Delimit words based on whitespace, punctuation, and quotes 
    StringTokenizer parser = new StringTokenizer(currentLine);
    while (parser.hasMoreTokens()) { 
    String currentWord = parser.nextToken(); 

    Integer frequency = frequencyMap.get(currentWord); 

    // Add the word if it doesn't already exist, otherwise increment the 
    // frequency counter. 
    if (frequency == null) { 
    frequency = 0; 
    } 
    frequencyMap.put(currentWord, frequency + 1); 
    }
    StringTokenizer parser2 = new StringTokenizer(currentLine2);
    while (parser2.hasMoreTokens()) { 
        String currentWord2 = parser2.nextToken(); 

        Integer frequency = frequencyMap.get(currentWord2); 

        // Add the word if it doesn't already exist, otherwise increment the 
        // frequency counter. 
        if (frequency == null) { 
        frequency = 0; 
        } 
        frequencyMap.put(currentWord2, frequency + 1); 

        } 
    }

    // Display our nice little Map 
    System.out.println(frequencyMap);
```

But for the following file-

> ISCHEMIA-GLUTAMATE
>   ISCHEMIA-BRAIN
>   GLUTAMATE-BRAIN
>   BRAIN-TOLERATE
>   BRAIN-TOLERATE
>   TOLERATE-BRAIN
>   GLUTAMATE-ISCHEMIA
>   ISCHEMIA-GLUTAMATE

I am getting the following output-

> {glutamate-brain=1, ischemia-glutamate=3, ischemia-brain=1, glutamate-ischemia=3, brain-tolerate=3, brain-ischemia=1, tolerate-brain=3, brain-glutamate=1}

The problem is in second while block I think. Any light on this problem will be highly appreciated.

Comment: please add the expected output...

Comment: {ischemia-glutamate=3, ischemia-brain=1, glutamate-brain=1,brain-tolerate=3}

Comment: Use a debugger or add System.out.println() debug traces to trace your program run and the values of variables as it runs and figure out when/why it is adding new entries instead of incrementing existing ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an algorithm perspective, you may want to consider the following approach:

For each string, split, then sort, then re-combine (i.e. take DEF-ABC and convert to ABC-DEF.  ABC-DEF would convert to ABC-DEF).  Then use that as the key for your frequency count.

If you need to hold onto the exact original item, just include that in your key - so the key would have:  ordinal (the re-combined string) and original.

Comment: Another way to do this is to write a key class that will be instantiated with the original "ABC-DEF" string, tokenize it internally, sort it and then use the list of sorted tokens to implement equals and hashCode.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I stole the **sweet trick** suggested by **Kevin Day** for my implementation.*

I still want to post just to let you know that using the right data structure ([Multiset/Bad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset)) and the right libraries ([google-guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)) will not only *simplify* the code but also makes it *efficient*.

### Code

```
public class BasicFrequencyCalculator
{
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Multiset<Word> frequency = Files.readLines(new File("c:/2.txt"), Charsets.ISO_8859_1, new LineProcessor() {

            private final Multiset<Word> result = HashMultiset.create();

            @Override
            public Object getResult()
            {
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean processLine(final String line) throws IOException
            {
                result.add(new Word(line));
                return true;
            }
        });
        for (Word w : frequency.elementSet())
        {
            System.out.println(w.getOriginal() + " = " + frequency.count(w));
        }
    }
}


public class Word
{
    private final String key;

    private final String original;

    public Word(final String orig)
    {
        this.original = orig.trim();
        String[] temp = original.toLowerCase().split("-");
        Arrays.sort(temp);
        key = temp[0] + "-"+temp[1];
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((getKey() == null) ? 0 : getKey().hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj)
    {
        if (this == obj)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Word))
        {
            return false;
        }
        Word other = (Word) obj;
        if (getKey() == null)
        {
            if (other.getKey() != null)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (!getKey().equals(other.getKey()))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return getOriginal();
    }

    public String getKey()
    {
        return key;
    }

    public String getOriginal()
    {
        return original;
    }
}
```

### Output

```
BRAIN-TOLERATE     = 3
ISCHEMIA-GLUTAMATE = 3
GLUTAMATE-BRAIN    = 1
ISCHEMIA-BRAIN     = 1
```

Comment: Nice implementation!  BTW - be sure to include a separator (that doesn't appear in any of the strings) in your Word.key computation, otherwise you can get conflicts (e.g. ABCD != AB-CD).  key=temp[0] +   "\u0001" + key[1].  A more robust way to do it would be to store the sorted key array and implement comparable to loop through the keys, etc... that way you don't have to worry about ensuring that the separator isn't part of the string itself.  This, of course, could be further encapsulated by creating a ComparableStringList class.

Comment: oh yeah - I think you meant Multiset / Bag (not 'Bad') - I didn't want to edit it just in case I was mis-reading it...

Comment: Yes two things to notice are Multiset (Datastructure) and the library (Files and LineProcessor from google collections) makes this very simple. There are other enhancements as well like this doesn't work across all locales/languages unless I use Collator, BreakIterator etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help. Here is how I solved it-

```
// Mapping of String->Integer (word -> frequency) 
    TreeMap<String, Integer> frequencyMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(); 

    // Iterate through each line of the file 
    String[] temp;
    String currentLine; 
    String currentLine2;
    while ((currentLine = in.readLine()) != null) { 

    temp=currentLine.split("-");
    currentLine2=temp[1]+"-"+temp[0];

    // Iterate through each word of the current line  
    StringTokenizer parser = new StringTokenizer(currentLine);
    while (parser.hasMoreTokens()) { 
    String currentWord = parser.nextToken(); 

    Integer frequency = frequencyMap.get(currentWord);  
    Integer frequency2 = frequencyMap.get(currentLine2);

    // Add the word if it doesn't already exist, otherwise increment the 
    // frequency counter. 
    if (frequency == null) {
        if (frequency2 == null)
            frequency = 0;
        else {
            frequencyMap.put(currentLine2, frequency2 + 1);
            break;
        }//else
    } //if (frequency == null)

    frequencyMap.put(currentWord, frequency + 1);
    }//while (parser.hasMoreTokens())

    }//while ((currentLine = in.readLine()) != null)

    // Display our nice little Map 
    System.out.println(frequencyMap);
```

Comment: If this is for homework or learning purposes, this code is fine. But if this is going to be part of some business app that is going to be under maintenance for a while then this is going to be a maintenance nightmare. Try simplifying this.

Comment: Thanks Pangea... just learning. I know the code is not optimized at all and not looking good.